# How to use reactive forms valueChanges debounce for first save without getting in a loop by patching the id

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get a debounce on input of my form fields, if the form is fresh and contains no ID when I create and receive the record back from the database I need to patch the form with the new values. { id, updatedAt etc }, however when using the valueChanges debounce subscription this results in an infinite loop as every time the form is patched valueChanges fires again.

I could use `(input)="saveClient(clientForm)"` on the form inputs but I cant figure out how to get that to debounce.

```
  /**
    * On init
    *
    * @returns {void}
    */
    public ngOnInit (): void {
        this.clientForm = this.clientService.getForm({})
        this.subscriptions.push(
            this.clientForm.valueChanges
            .debounceTime(1000)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .subscribe((data) => {
                this.saveClient(this.clientForm)
            })
        )

        this.display = true
    }

   /**
    * Save client
    *
    * @param {FormGroup} clientForm Client form
    *
    * @returns {void}
    */
    public saveClient (clientForm: FormGroup) {
        return this.clientService.api.save(clientForm.value)
        .toPromise()
        .then((result) => {
            clientForm.patchValue(result)
            return result
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to patch the value without emitting an event. Like this:

```
clientForm.patchValue(result, { emitEvent: false });
```

> If emitEvent is true, this change will cause a valueChanges event on the FormControl to be emitted. This defaults to true (as it falls through to updateValueAndValidity).

[Docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#members)

Comment: Thanks very much, I didn't think to check If patchValue had options.

Comment: Glad I could help.